# I have a Google Drive app that I created, should I be hiding the client secret from users of the app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I have a Google Drive app I created that helps upload and download files from the command line. It uses a client secret and client id variable to get a refresh token, which I understand to be the user's identification. I am wondering if the secret is something I need to hide from users.

It seems I can get to the auth app page where the user selects their email account without the client secret, but when asking for a refresh token using the verification code, it doesn't go through.

How should I treat my app client secret credential I obtained from `https://console.developers.google.com/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [TOS](https://developers.google.com/terms/) that you agreed to when you created your client

[image]

The Client id and client secret identify your application to google.  All requests that come though the auth server with your client id and secret are assumed to be coming from your application.  If you give someone else access to that they can then create their own application using your client id and secret and to everyone google, the users it will still appear to be your application.  Any spamming will assume to be you and will get your account blocked, any charges against the quota will assume to be you and applied to your billing account.

You may not share your client id and secret This should be kept embedded in your application for only you and your developers to see.

If this cant be done then you will need to instruct your users on how to create their own project on Google Developer console and create their own client id and secret and how to go though the verification process.

## Refresh token private user data

Refresh tokens are actually your applications permissions to access a users data, with that and the client id and secrete anyone can create an access token and access private user data.  Which again appears in the TOS

[image]

Comment: When you say "kept embedded", does this mean I need to put some sort of an encryption on it? Or would plain text be permissible given that I keep it deep inside the app somewhere?

Comment: If i can open a plan text file then i have access to it, i can abuse your client id and client secret.  You need to compiled as as part of a Dll, or released as a web application hosted on a server for example.  You cant just share the source code to someone  which contains a clear text client id and client secret is not permitted.

Comment: so basically the clientid and secret should be consider user credentials and treated as such? is correct to simply treat them the same as one would would treat a username and password on a webapplication?